# Search on a list

Tags: list, search, cswp

Is there any possibility to make a CSWP to search on a list and then return the results like a list itself? And, is it possible to this CSWP to search inside the links on this same list?

I'm not sure if i made myself clear, but that is the main problem I'm facing right now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query

```
{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople Path:{\SiteCollection.URL}/Form-ListURL/}
```

Let me know if you have any questions